# Authentication in Django is_authenticated

Tags: django

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/) of the on `is_authenticated` function on the User model read:

> **is_authenticated**
>   Read-only attribute which is always True (as opposed
>   to AnonymousUser.is_authenticated which is always False). This is a
>   way to tell if the user has been authenticated. This does not imply
>   any permissions and doesn’t check if the user is active or has a valid
>   session. Even though normally you will check this attribute on
>   request.user to find out whether it has been populated by the
>   AuthenticationMiddleware (representing the currently logged-in user),
>   you should know this attribute is True for any User instance.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
```

is_authenticated says that it doesn't check whether a user has a valid session, isn't that technically false because on each request the Session table is checked against the client session cookie and only returns a User if there is a match?
Otherwise you wouldnt be able to return a User if the client doesnt not send authentication details like username, password?

Comment: Maybe it should be doesnt only check whether a student is currently logged in or not

Comment: It checks whether an instance exists but if called on the request.user can be used to check whether a valid sessions exists since request.user is only User if there is a valid session for the client session cookie